# What is the de-facto supported Conditional Random Fields package for C++?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, crf

The few packages I've found haven't been updated in over a year.  I was wondering what the standard CRF package was for C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Name             Released     Downloads in 2011

CRFSuite 0.12    2011-08      ~800

CRF++ 0.54       2010-05      ~11000

FlexCRFs 0.3     2007-04      ~800
```

Answer (score 2):

For linear chains CRF I would recommend [crfsuite](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/) or [wapiti](http://wapiti.limsi.fr/). Both are in C hence usable from C++. Both are very fast and well maintained.

Comment: Why not CRF++?~